# Unable to Dequeue viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind 'the view returned was not retrieved'

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

I have a `collectionView` with 2 sections. I am trying to `dequeueReusableSupplementaryView` however.  I am getting the following error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'the view returned from
>   -collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath (UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, {length = 2, path = 1 - 0}) was not retrieved by
>   calling
>   -dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
>   or is nil

Here is my code:

```
enum HomeSection: Int, CaseIterable {
    case companies = 0, reviews
}

private var sections = [HomeSection]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        sections = [.companies, .reviews]
        setUpView()
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let companyCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Identifier.companyCell, for: indexPath) as! CompanyCell
        let reviewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Identifier.reviewCell, for: indexPath) as! ReviewCell
        switch sections[indexPath.section] {
        case .companies:
            let company = self.companies[indexPath.item]
            companyCell.company = company
            return companyCell
        case .reviews:
            let review = self.reviews[indexPath.item]
            reviewCell.review = review
            return reviewCell
        }
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    switch sections[indexPath.section] {
    case .companies:
        switch kind {
        case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader:
            let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: Identifier.headerView, for: indexPath) as! HeaderView
            return headerView
        case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter:
            let footerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: Identifier.footerView, for: indexPath) as! FooterView
            return footerView
        default:
            return UICollectionReusableView()
        }
    case .reviews:
        switch kind {
        case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader:
            return UICollectionReusableView()
        case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter:
            return UICollectionReusableView()
        default:
            return UICollectionReusableView()
        }
    }
}
```

I have ensured I have all my cells and supplementaryViews registered.

### Registered Cells, Headers & Footers

```
private let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true
    let view = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    view.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    view.register(CompanyCell.self,
                  forCellWithReuseIdentifier: Identifier.companyCell)
    view.register(ReviewCell.self,
                  forCellWithReuseIdentifier: Identifier.reviewCell)
    view.register(HeaderView.self,
                  forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader,
                  withReuseIdentifier: Identifier.headerView)
    view.register(FooterView.self,
                  forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter,
                  withReuseIdentifier: Identifier.footerView)
    return view
}()
```

Comment: can you show the cells you register as supp and how you register them

Comment: I've updated the question with registered cells, headers & footers

Comment: do you create them programmatically or xib ?

Comment: All programmatically. They are currently just holding a UILabel and of course the required initializers. The problem seems to be with the IndexPath however, I have switched the sections correctly I believe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you are returning a view that was either (a) not returned by `dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind`; or (b) is `nil`. Judging on the error message, it would appear to be having a problem with the `UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter` for the second section.

You are returning `UICollectionReusableView()` in quite a few places. That is not valid and will result in this error. You have to return an actual dequeued supplementary view (or configure your collection view so that `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` won’t be called for that section kind).

Comment: solved this by adding
assert(false, "Unexpected element kind") if the view should return nil.

Comment: As far as I know, `asserts` only work for debug, not for release builds.

Comment: Yeah. And because of that, you still have to return the dummy value or else the compiler will complain. I personally use `fatalError`, and the compiler knows that execution cannot proceed and will validate your code on that basis (e.g., not only freeing you from returning some dummy value, but even warning you about putting in code that is unreachable. `preconditionFailure` is another option.

Answer (score 0):

if you not using **UICollectionViewController** must be called the register inside **the init()**

or if you create a collectionView in UIViewController you must declare the collectionView as **lazy var** not **let**

***example***

```
private let headerIdentifer = "Cell"
private let reuseIdentifer = "Header"

private lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.delegate = self
    cv.dataSource = self
    cv.register(CellView.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifer)
    cv.register(HeaderView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: headerIdentifer)
    cv.backgroundColor = .clear
    cv.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    return cv
}()
```